# Convert numeric array to cell array of chars and concat with chars in one line

Tags: arrays, matlab, char, cell-array, string-conversion

How to convert numeric array to cell array of chars and concat with chars in one line?

**Example**:

I have a numeric array:

```
[1, 5, 12, 17]
```

I want to convert it to a cell array of chars and concat with the chars 'Sensor ' and get:

```
{'Sensor 1', 'Sensor 5', 'Sensor 12', 'Sensor 17'}
```

Is there a way to do this in one line?

**I got for now:**

```
nums = [1, 5, 12, 17];

cellfun(@(x) ['Sensor ' num2str(x)], num2cell(nums), 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

Is there a simpler or more compact way?

Comment: I think, your current solution is very simple and compact. And, it's already a one-liner. So, why wasting time on saving maybe a few characters of source code? :)

Comment: @HansHirse: For such a simple task, it's not so compact, it seem to me that there should be a simpler - shorter solution.

Comment: A simpler, shorter solution might not necessarily be simpler. [Readable code](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11style/) is almost always more important than smartly written code, unless you're competing in code obfuscation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it slightly neater using `sprintf()` and `arrayfun()` but not sure this saves you a lot:

```
nums = [1, 5, 12, 17];

arrayfun(@(x) {sprintf('Sensor %d',x)}, nums) % Gives a cell array of char array strings

arrayfun(@(x) sprintf("Sensor %d",x), nums)   % Gives an array of string strings (version 2016b onwards)
```

You can also use `compose()` in versions of MATLAB from 2016a onwards:

```
compose('Sensor %d', nums)  % Char array

compose("Sensor %d", nums)  % String array (version 2017a onwards)
```

Comment: Thanks! that's neater than my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which only uses functions "Introduced before R2006a", is:

```matlab
A = [1, 5, 12, 17];
B = strcat('Sensor', {' '}, strtrim(cellstr(int2str(A.'))) );
```

This produces a column vector - so you should transpose as needed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative using strings:

```
>> nums = [1, 5, 12, 17];
>> cellstr("Sensor " + nums) 

ans =

  1×4 cell array

    {'Sensor 1'}    {'Sensor 5'}    {'Sensor 12'}    {'Sensor 17'}
```

Strings require [MATLAB R2017a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html).